# How does Select Distinct work on a Primary Key in SQL?

Tags: sql, query-optimization, distinct, optimization

How does the SQL Optimizer handle Select Distinct on a primary key? For eg

Employee Table - (EmpId int primary key, EmpName)

`select distinct EmpId from Employee.`

Would the optimizer reject the distinct keyword considering EmpId is already distinct?

Comment: what does the Execution plan say?

Comment: What do you use to run the query? It's really a question of implementation of primary key indexing

Comment: It'll Ignore `Distinct` and `Group By` on Unique Indexes in SQL server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried under Oracle 11g and they produce different results.

```
select USERID from TPM_USER
```

Produces:

```
SELECT STATEMENT    7.0 7   242479  667 2668    7                   ALL_ROWS                                            
TABLE ACCESS (FULL) 7.0 7   242479  667 2668    1   TPMDBO  TPM_USER    FULL    TABLE   ANALYZED    1
```

And:

```
select distinct USERID from TPM_USER
```

Produces:

```
SELECT STATEMENT    8.0 7   24725738    667 2668    8                   ALL_ROWS                                            
HASH (UNIQUE)   8.0 7   24725738    667 2668    1           UNIQUE                                                  
TABLE ACCESS (FULL) 7.0 7   242479  667 2668    1   TPMDBO  TPM_USER    FULL    TABLE   ANALYZED    1
```

`USERID` is the primary key on `TPM_USER` in case that wasn't clear.

**UPDATE:**

I was somewhat irked that Oracle could be this stupid, so I tried the same queries on our production server which has about a thousand times more data.  This time, the two query plans were identical (the index was used both times, and no full table scan was done).  This leads me to believe the planner will take the table statistics into account when deciding which route to go.

Production (with or without `DISTINCT`):

```
SELECT STATEMENT    3.0 3   461492  3521    14084   3                   ALL_ROWS                                            
INDEX (FAST FULL SCAN)  3.0 3   461492  3521    14084   1   TPMDBO  TPM_USER_PK FAST FULL SCAN  INDEX (UNIQUE)  ANALYZED
```

Comment: That's correct, Oracle changes the execution plan according to statistics, that's why it is good to **gather statistics** on your tables (specially those whit lots of inserts, updates and deletes) every while.

Answer (score 5):

Try it both with and without the DISTINCT keyword and compare execution plans.

SQL Server will produce identical plans for both. YMMV for other RDBMSs.

Comment: Also comparing `SELECT DISTINCT NonKeyColumn FROM Employee` might help to gain insight

Answer (score 1):

There can't be a fixed rule for your question, and each database can handle this by its own way. You must look at your database's execution plan for the query.

But I believe modern productional databases such as Oracle, MySQL, Postgres, ... just ignore the distinct word and just iterate over the index (and not the table).

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't produce identical plans for me.

Querying with distinct on a non-indexed column uses a hash match, whereas querying on the primary key doesn't bother to do that.

Comment: That is, doesn't produce identical results between pk and non-pk column.  It does, of course, produce the same results whether you use DISTINCT on a pk or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by rejected, but given that, by definition, primary keys are non-NULL and unique, I'm sure the sorting/grouping operation is simply ignored as unnecessary for purposes of generating an execution plan in most RDBMS systems.